# Quickblox API group_by query on CustomObject

Tags: ios, sql, rest, group-by, quickblox

I want to retrieve all customObjects With latest date group_by user_id.
How can I make this request in IOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *getRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[getRequest setObject:@"user_id" forKey:@"group_by"];
[getRequest setObject:@"max" forKey:@"created_at[calc]"];

[QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName:@"MyClass" extendedRequest:getRequest delegate:self];
```